# What's the best way to execute a system command

Tags: go

I need to get the output of a query like this `whois '-i origin XXX' | grep ..."` and save it in variables in go. How can I do it? Should I run the command on the system through go or is there any web api that I could use to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os/exec` package in go. This will take some arguments and it will run the system command.

Example :

```
cmd := exec.Command(appname, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3)   //cmd should be in path variable
stdout, err := cmd.Output()        //Running command
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())         // If error come it will print it
    return
}
fmt.Print(string(stdout))     // Printing the output of the command.
```

For Reference please check -> https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/